# Wait until foreach finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently I am using node-mysql (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) and for each result it returns from the database I have to perform several functions. Currently, it attempts to complete everything at once, however is there anyway to make it wait until each function is complete before moving to the next result from mysql?

```
connection.query('select * from data', function(err, rows) {
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     doThis(rows[i].axn, rows[i].dnq, rows[i].bgq);
 }
});
```

In the doThis function, if certain requirements are met than it passes the data to another function. How can I make sure that those are completed *first* before moving until the next query row?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If anything in `doThis` is asynchronous, I don't think you can. You'd have to use the concept of callbacks and recursion to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this pretty cleanly with the [`forEachSerial`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachseriesarr-iterator-callback) method of the `async` library if you have your `doThis` function support a callback parameter that it calls when its work is done.

Something like this:

```
connection.query('select * from data', function(err, rows) {
    async.forEachSeries(rows, function(row, callback) {
        doThis(row.axn, row.dnq, row.bgq, callback);
    }, function(err) {
        // All done
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` event is fired on each row of data, see [documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#streaming-query-rows)

```
connection.query('select * from data')
  .on('result', function(row) {
     doThis(row.axn, row.dnq, row.bgq);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't even see this! I will try this, thanks again.